# sh: virtuemart_user_id: command not found

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, joomla3.0, virtuemart

Helo,

This error appeared in my error.log. We are using AWS's Elastic Beanstalk with an EC2 instance with PHP, Joomla 3.4.8 and VM 3.0.12

I have tried to link the error with the access.log to see if it was related with a specific URL. But it is hard since I don't get the date inside the log when the

> sh: virtuemart_user_id: command not found

appears.

I have read, related with this issue, that it could be something related with ubuntu. I have searched for shell_exec() and exec() inside the project to see if virtuemart was trying to execute a command, but I didn't get nothing like that.

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell_exec() and exec() methods are not the only way to execute commands, you can use the backsticks (`) like this: `$output = ls -al; echo "<pre>$output</pre>";` (read this entry from php documentation for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)

Since you are using virtuemart, I guess virtuemart_user_id might be one of your database fields. This kind of fields are often refered to by using the backsticks marks (in this case, `virtuemart_user_id`).

Are you sure you are always using `virtuemart_user_id` inside string variables?